# Responsive NavBar Only using CSS and html

Tags: html, css

My Media Query dropdown doesn't work properly is there something that i missed out?

[Dropdown Image mess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbKYV.png)

In JSfiddle it doesn't allow me to use the dropdown.
and in my Visual Studio after running it will have the Dropdown image mess.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
.topnav.responsive .icon {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
}
.topnav.responsive a {
float: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}
.topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
.topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
.topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
 display:block;
 width: 100%;
text-align: left;
```

Something is wrong...
Please help.
   https://jsfiddle.net/0tugk2L5/8/

Comment: To make your fiddle work change Load Type in the JavaScript settings to  No wrap-in<body>. (dropdown menu in JS field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed width issue by removing `width: 100%` from this part of your code:

```
 .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
   display:block;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: left;
 }
```

Was that only problem?

UPD: 
I've add `.dropdown-content {top: 0;}` to media query for small screen size and works great
https://jsfiddle.net/aesk9y9v/1/

Comment: When i hover over Category there is a grey blank space that is one of the issue as well..

Comment: Got it! Issue was called by positioning .dropdown-content. Check upd to answer

Comment: Thank you you fixed my issue!